# Indefinite integration of $1/\sqrt{3-5x-2x^2}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Cannot make it out.

$$\int \frac{dx}{(3-5x-2x^2)^{1/2}} $$

Is the problem correct, or does it have errors?
I have a doubt.

Comment: Please format your post using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, without further information, how can we tell if the problem is correct? The integrand you give is certainly integrable in elementary terms.

Comment: **Hint:** [Complete the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), and use a [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).

Answer (score 4):

This function is integrable in elementary terms.

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{3-5x-2x^2}}\,dx=\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot\arcsin\left(\dfrac{4x+5}7\right)+C$$

It can be done with a combination of complete the square and rewriting the integral into an integral definition of $\arcsin x$.
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\arcsin x+ C$$